# SML list equality oddness

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have this bit of code:

```
fun foldr2(f, x::xs) =
    if xs = [] then
      x
    else
      f(x, foldr2(f, xs))
```

With the type signature

```
(''a * ''a -> ''a) * ''a list -> ''a
```

Looks pretty straight-forward, it takes a function that works over equality types and a list of equality type as arguments, because of the `xs = []` comparison. However, for some reason it works on input such as `(op +, [2.3, 2.7, 4.0])`, when in SML/NJ reals are not an equality type. Can anyone help me shed some light on why this magic occurs?

Comment: +1, I also wonder why this works. It's just as if SML/NJ translates the condition block to "null [2.3, 2.7, 4.0]" or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's to do with the magical way in which `+` is overloaded for reals.  To me, this *almost* verges on being a compiler bug, although I would have to look at the SML97 definition to see exactly what the correct behaviour is meant to be.  The overloading over `+` is something of a nasty dark corner in SML, IMHO.

For example, if you define a function that is of type `real * real -> real` and pass that as an argument to `foldr2` you get the type error you were expecting:

```
fun f (x : real * real) = 134.5
foldr2 (f, [1.4, 2.25, 7.0])
  stdIn:8.1-8.29 Error: operator and operand don't agree [equality type required]
```

You can even induce the type error if you just add a type annotation to `op +`, which basically led me to the conclusion that it is the overloading of `+` that is causing the mysterious effect.